# How to forward Apache requests to Tomcat for a specific subdirectory?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'm trying to integrate Tomcat into an existing Apache environment on a Ubuntu 22.04 server. Apache has been working great and now I have installed Tomcat, have set up ports, and have gotten everything ready for AJP.

In the sites-enabled directory, I've added the following to the conf file that handles https connections on port 443 (the conf file for port 80 forwards to this 443 one):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        #this block was added after installing Tomcat
        <IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
         ProxyPass /wapps/* ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/webapps/
        </IfModule>
        #end of new block
        
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        #mydomain.com is not my real fqdn. my real fqdn is actually there
        DocumentRoot /webroot/html/internetpublic/default/
        <Directory /webroot/html/internetpublic/default>
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

#other ssl things, that are working well are below
..
```

I need to configure to forward any requests of the directory /wapps/ to go to Tomcat and launch the necessary servlet from Tomcat's webapps directory. Thus, https://example.com/wapps/MyWebapp/MyServlet should be forwarded to Tomcat to run MyWebapp/MyServlet. Everything else is handled by "regular" Apache. However, the above config doesn't seem to be forwarding correctly.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what may be wrong?

Comment: Not quite programming related ([help/on-topic]). But you might want to look up the AJP connector, which requires a secret to be configured as well: I don't see that.

Comment: "webapps" is only the name of a folder in a Tomcat installation, it is usually not part of your web application's URL. What is inside your webapps folder?